# Android - Switch track height

Tags: android, android-switch

I want to have a custom Switch which I can define the *Thumb* and *Track* drawables.

Setting the *thumb* (no problem here):

```
android:thumb="@drawable/switch_button_selector"
```

Setting the *track*:

```
android:track="@drawable/switch_bg"
```

*switch_bg* is a drawable (image) on res/drawable folder and it is not a 9 patch image.

Happens that this drawable is being resized in height.

I want to keep its original size (width/height) without stretching the drawable.

**Note:** The *thumb* is bigger (in height) than the *track*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have the switch_bg image the **exact same size** as the thumb resource.

2 options for that:

**1)** Edit the image (png/etc) to have transparent spacing where it is needed to match the size of the thumb

**2)** Create a new drawable resource file of [layer-list](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) and add the switch_bg as a child. There you can set inner padding so that the overall resource will fit in size to the thumb

Comment: I went with first approach, with editing the Track drawable to have the same height as Thumb drawable.

Comment: Good call :) That is the better option!